# Selectively executing unit tests with googletest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Let's say I have classes A, B, C and each has its own unit test in gtest.

How can I run only A test? I have this main.cpp for executing all the unit tests available.

[This page](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#temporarily-disabling-tests) recommends to use `DISABLED_` in front of the class name, but it requires me to change many parts of test code.

I guess there could be a better way to control which test to run or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc,  char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n";

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS(); // <-- return "RUN_XYZ_TEST()" ???
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile this program, you will get an executable that I will call `program`.

Now, if you call `program` with `--gtest_list_tests` (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#listing-test-names) you will get all tests that are enable to run. If you want to run a specific one (as in your example, test A), just call your application as (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests):

> program --gtest_filter=A

Note that you can apply wildcards too. To get a list of all options, try:

> program --help

Comment: Well, even when I give the module name, google test seems to run all the tests anyway.